# "Unrecognized attribute 'secure'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive." when running website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am having a problem with configuring my ASP.NET project on IIS. I have exactly 2 same servers (I mean same IIS settings everything) created from the same image. However, one is working fine, while for the other one, I am facing the problem "***Unrecognized attribute 'secure'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.***" (pls see the screenshot below)

[image: IIS Error "Unrecognized attribute 'secure'"]

Does anyone know what might be the root cause of this and how to resolve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by an incorrect .net version, you can try follow steps:

1. Check on which .NET version the application is developed. Let's assume, it's .NET 4.0.
2. Open IIS Manager and find the Application Pool, on which your website is hosted.
3. Go to that Application Pool and check the .NET version and change it to 4.0 accordingly by clicking on Basic and Advanced Settings.
4. If .NET 4.0 is not listed, go ahead and install it.
5. If it still won't show up, go to command prompt and fire the below command to find a list of ASP.NET versions installed: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -lv`
6. In the output, if .NET 4.0 is not listed, register it by firing the below command: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -I`.
7. It should show up as .NET 4.0 in the .NET Framework Version dropdown for the application pool.